# How to know in mysql that table is empty by writing query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 select * from users;
```

will return all the users in the table, but sometime my table may be empty. I want to check.

```
  "select if empty users else continue";
```

this type of SQL I want.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will tell you the number of rows in the table

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users
```

You also might want to have a look at [EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: thank you, it is not exact solution for me but at least give me some idea to go through.